Selecting from SYSTEM VERSIONING with BETWEEN not working?
Forgive me if I'm just misreading the results, but I'm not sure why I'm seeing the results I'm getting given the criteria for the system version (temporal table) query.
select registration_date,order_number,id,row_start,row_end from registration FOR SYSTEM_TIME BETWEEN '2024-04-04 19:10' and NOW() limit 5;
+---------------------+--------------+----+----------------------------+----------------------------+
| registration_date   | order_number | id | row_start                  | row_end                    |
+---------------------+--------------+----+----------------------------+----------------------------+
| 2013-02-15 14:54:50 | NULL         |  1 | 2024-04-04 19:03:18.695546 | 2038-01-19 03:14:07.999999 |
| 2013-02-15 14:54:49 | NULL         |  2 | 2024-04-04 19:03:18.695546 | 2038-01-19 03:14:07.999999 |
| 2013-02-15 14:54:49 | NULL         |  3 | 2024-04-04 19:03:18.695546 | 2038-01-19 03:14:07.999999 |
| 2013-02-15 14:54:49 | NULL         |  4 | 2024-04-04 19:03:18.695546 | 2038-01-19 03:14:07.999999 |
| 2013-02-15 14:58:10 | NULL         |  5 | 2024-04-04 19:03:18.695546 | 2038-01-19 03:14:07.999999 |
+---------------------+--------------+----+----------------------------+----------------------------+

Looking at the row_start I would expect records only AFTER 2024-04-04 19:10 UP TO NOW()
But I'm seeing records BEFORE the start date.
I am running that query straight from the mariadb console inside the docker image.
I am using MariaDB 11.3.2-MariaDB-1.11.3.2+maria~ubu2204 which is the current latest MariaDB docker image.

As the documentation says,

BETWEEN start AND end will show all rows that were visible at any point between two specified points in time

(inclusive).
All the rows you show have a row_end of the maximum timestamp value, and their (row_start,row_end) period definitely intersects your specified time range.
If you want different constraints than the syntax provides, you can wrap your query in an outer query and check them.  For instance, to find all rows visible sometime between a and b but excluding ones that started before c, do:
select * from (
    select *, row_start, row_end
    from t for system_time between a and b
) visible_sometime 
where row_start >= c


No, I mean BETWEEN. According to that doc, I should be seeing records for only BETWEEN the start and end which I take to mean STARTING from my start date. Right? it should be narrowing the search from my start date up until the current time the query runs.

If you look at my time, I want records after 19:10 but it brought back records as early as 19:03 which I would expect records AFTER or ON 19:10 and higher

@Tim it only returned records that still existed at 19:10 and later, which is what the documentation says.  it sounds like to do what you want you will need a subquery.  can you explain exactly what rows you are trying to find?

no, the doc does not mean starting between your start and end.  it means rows that were active at all between your start and end, nothing to do with when they started

@ysth is right, as the orders 1-5 where not deleted before 2024-04-04 19:10 they existed at that time of 2024-04-04 19:10, and therefore show in the original query.

Thanks, I see how it's working now. Thanks for the clarification, it was helpful. It's a very subtle difference from the way I was thinking.
